# how to rename a file if it's already exist

Tags: php

I made a function auto add _(number) to a uploaded file if they are already exist. However i'm having a problem that if i upload an image like image_1.jpg it will turn to image_1_1.jpg . How to make it turn to image_2.jpg. Here is my function:

```
$scan=scandir($destination);
$destination='C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\\';
function checkExist($name)
{

    global $scan;
    if(in_array($name,$scan))
    {
        $findDot=strpos($name,'.');
        $base=substr($name,0,$findDot);

        $extension=substr($name,$findDot);
        $i=1;
        $newName=$base.'_'.$i++.$extension;
        echo $newName;

        //the upload image will be renamed to .... in order to avoid same name  
    }
    else    
    {
        echo 'not found';
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to be more specific. How about files named file000009.jpg, file9iscool.jpg, 99.jpg for example?

Comment: if file exits then change the name

Comment: So if there's already a number in the name, you want to _increment_ it rather than simply tacking on _1? You'll have to examine the existing name, isolate any number fields, increment (one of them), glue the whole thing back together, check if the name is a duplicate of another file, repeat if necessary. You might use preg_match() to break up a filename into <non-numeric><number><the rest of it>.

Comment: I want it auto increase if an use keep upload an existing file. if image.jpg already exist. The function will add _1 at the end of name. However if the user upload another image.jpg it will turn to image_2.jpg and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you could check with `preg_match` if the new filename matches to the string. i.e:

```
preg_match("/^[\w]+\_+[\d]+.jpg/", $uploadedFile);
```

if so then split it, remove the last number...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for renaming image in PHP before uploading to the server. appending timestamp, unique id, image dimensions plus random number etc.

First, Check if the image filename exists in the hosted image folder otherwise upload it. The while loop checks if the image file name exists and appends a unique id as shown below ...

```
$actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$i = 1;
while(file_exists('tmp/'.$actual_name.".".$extension))
{           
    $actual_name = (string)$original_name.$i;
    $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
    $i++;
}
```